# VirtualBox menu gone

Tags: virtualbox

I've accidentally hidden the menu on VirtualBox, it used to have options to start a machine & I think have the snapshot options in too. It's been like this for a while as I cannot figure out any way to get it back and need to use the snapshot functionality.

I've put a screenshot of what I've currently got below for you to see, the menu used to be directly below the close button spanning the width of the VirtualBox window.

[image]

Comment: Turns out this is a duplicate question as marked by others. Was completely unable to find either of the other answered while I was looking though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click in the border at the bottom of the window and select "show toolbar".  The border at the bottom of the window is called the "statusbar" which is the other selection.

Comment: Thank you! For something that is so simple you have no idea how much time I've spent across multiple days trying to figure that out.

Comment: It's definitely hidden! I have no idea what one would do if you deselected both check marks - don't try it at home!